# iphone to flash communication

Tags: iphone, flash, sockets, networking

I was looking this new game (http://kijjaa.com/air/) that uses the iPhone as a control pad for a flash game in your computer browser. I tried to monitor the HTTP activity of the browser but it doesn't seem to be using the HTTP protocol.

Do you know how does this works? It's sockets programming? Can the flash movie become a socket server?

Comment: Contact the developer, generally they are willing to push you into the right direction.

Comment: FWIW: http://kijjaa.com/air/about/#how-it-works

Answer (score 0):

I would say, they are using something similar to this:

> *@tomkrcha*
>   Videotutorial: Controlling
>   the desktop with your mobile device
>   via P2P http://bit.ly/mAg8rD For iOS,
>   Playbook, Android. #AIR